# JSHint and eclipse plugin

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jshint

So I just installed JSHint in Eclipse Kepler
I loaded my .jshintrc file .

How do I run jshint on my javascript files? I do not see a menu item nor a place to specify filenames, etc...

Can someone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After adding a `.jshintrc` file to the root of the project you need to:

Right-click on your project in the Project Explorer view -> properties -> JSHint -> Configuration -> Check enable.

Also select the folders containing your js files (use slashes in the path).
I split my js files into two folders `custom` and `external` and only check on custom (and all subfolders of custom).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [`jshint-eclipse` issue](https://github.com/eclipsesource/jshint-eclipse/issues/29):

> You have to explicitly enable JSHint for your project.
>   You can do so by adding a file pattern on the `JSHint` page in your project's preferences.

The main contributor to [`jshint-eclipse`](https://github.com/eclipsesource/jshint-eclipse), [ralfstx](https://github.com/ralfstx), comments:

> Maybe it's not obvious.
>   I wanted to avoid checking all files by default for performance reasons.
>   JSHint is written in JavaScript, and running large scripts is not exactly fast.
>
> OTOH, checking all `*.js` files by default (maybe excluding `.min.js` files) would not affect non-JS projects, and for JS-only workspaces, checking all projects is probably useful...