# Validation errors using async/await in Eclipse Photon

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation, async-await

How can I get Eclipse to validate code containing async / await statements

```
async function f() {
    let x = await someAsyncCall();
    return x;
}
```

without showing "Semi-colon expected" and "'async' is not defined" errors?

I have tried a couple IDE / Plugin combinations, lately "Photon Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers" together with the Nodeclipse plugin.

I am unable to get the validator to handle this correctly, even if I set Project -> Preferences -> JavaScript -> Tern -> Version to ECMAScript 6.

Any ideas? What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: The async and await operators were introduced in ECMAScript 2017 (ES8). Is there an option in Eclipse for ES8?

Comment: @JamieWeston As far as I know, there is no option. I just wrongly associated async / await with ES6.

Comment: I filed an Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545216

Comment: Did you solve this problem, I have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

[JSHint validator is going to support](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/3273) a few of ECMAScript 2017 standard features, including *async* and *await*, in the upcoming 2.10 version of the software tool.

Comment: What is the relation between Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers and JSHint? Does Eclipse use JSHint by default and an improved JSHint would mean an improved Eclipse experience, too? Or would I have to include JSHint in Eclipse somehow on my own?

Comment: It is not by default, you have to [install it](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/). Also, you might want to look at this [SoF question that discusses enabling option.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309397/jshint-and-eclipse-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself: Using the Wild Web Developer Plugin solves the problem. Don't forget to open the files in the Generic Text Editor (Right click -> Open With... -> Generic Text Editor).

see: https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/eclipse-wild-web-developer

Comment: What do you mean a "solution" ? Don't you lose all the language specific support then ?